# How to put quotes around single words in a string, but not around substrings that already have quotes?

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, unix

I'm pretty new to bash scripting. How do I convert a string that has both phrases and single words:

```
flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors
```

to a string that has quotes around each, also adding commas between them:

```
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this through the below Perl one-liner command,

```
$ s='flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors'
$ perl -pe 's/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|(\S+)/"\1",/g; s/,$//; s/"(?= *")/",/g' <<< "$s"
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - went with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v all '"%s", ' "${@}"
echo "${all%, }"
```

As an example:

```
script.sh flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors"
```

Explanation:

- `printf -v all '"%s", ' "${@}"`

  For each argument on the command line, this prints it to the variable `all` with added quotes, a comma, and a trailing space.

  This approach makes use of the shell's processing of command line arguments.  In particular, the shell interprets double-quoted strings on the command-line as a single argument and their quotes are removed by the shell before the script begins.
- `echo "${all%, }"`

  The variable `all` has an extra comma and space at the end.  This removes them and prints the result.

Hat tip: Rici.

#### Alternative

This `bash` approach is longer but might be easier to customize:

```
#!/bin/bash
for s in "$@"
do
    s=${s%\"}
    s=${s#\"}
    all="$all, \"$s\""
done
echo "${all#, }"
```

As an example:

```
$ script.sh flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors"
```

#### Explanation

- `for s in "$@"; do`

  This loops over every item on the command line.  Note that, on a command line, double-quoted strings are a single item.  Each argument is assigned, in turn, to the variable `s`.
- `s=${s%\"}; s=${s#\"}`

  These two statements remove double quotes, if any, from front or back of the string `s`.
- `all="$all, \"$s\""`

  This appends the current argument to the string `all`.
- `done`

  This completes the loop
- `echo "${all#, }"`

  The string `all` has an extra comma and space at the beginning.  This removes them and then displays the result on stdout.

#### Example of calling this from another script

```
tags=(flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors)
tags=($(bash script.sh "${tags[@]}"))
echo "${tags[@]}"
```

This produces the output:

```
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors"
```

Comment: `s=${s%\"}; s=${s#\"}` could be removed without changing the behaviour, at least on the sample input provided. Consequently, the whole thing could be replaced with `printf -v all '"%s", ' "${@}"; echo "{all%, }"`

Comment: Thanks. The first approach works fine if the script is called from the command line, however if the script is called from another script it puts double quotes around each word:    `tags=$(sh script.sh $tags)` results in the string `"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful", "yellow", "flowers", "nature", "colors"`

Comment: @dmlazar The key is how `tags` was defined before you pass it to the script.  I updated the answer with a section showing how to do that.  The solution is that `tags` should be an `bash` array rather than a string.

Comment: Thanks, now I'll know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk:

```
s='flowers yellow "beautiful yellow flowers" nature colors'
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' -v OFS=", " -v ORS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\"%s\"%s", $i, OFS;
    if (RT) print RT OFS}' <<< "$s"
"flowers", "yellow", "beautiful yellow flowers", "nature", "colors",
```